# Deploy,emt issue for ASP.NET Core App to local IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I am deploying ASP.NET Core Web API for the first time.

I am facing issues and confused on few things.

1) I followed this link [Host ASP.NET Core Web API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/) and have no issues until step 5. My Core Web API has Swagger UI and UI not showing up.

2) I followed this link [Deploy ASP.NET Core to IIS](https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/) and in step 3 I am not sure how he gets Add Application. My IIS always show Add website.

I followed this link too [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2). I tried from 2 days haven't get working on IIS.

I deployed using Web Deploy and Folder too. None of them worked

This is my Web Config file

After Diagnostics, I am here. Runtime doesnot match. I tried to install from that link and still not working.

[image: Diagnostics]

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SampleCoreApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Run a report and attach it to your question, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: I went through this. can you explain what Jexus Manager is?  For web sites opened in Jexus Manager, there is an action called ASP.NET Core Diagnostics showed.

Comment: You claimed that you have deployed the app to local IIS, then why do you run the report for IIS Express? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/iis.html Please rerun it for IIS, and that should reveal the exact info for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The first link is talking about hosting the **ASP.NET Web API** and not **ASP.NET Core Web API**.

When you are hosting **ASP.NET Core** app/api, you need to set the **.NET CLR version** of the application pool to **No Managed Code**

[image]

This is also mentioned in the **Step 3** of the second link. It's creating an application under the Default Web Site, that's where you see the **Add Application** option. It's not necessary to create an application under the Default Web Site.

[image]

- You can either create the **Application Pool** first and set it to **No Managed Code**. Then, when adding a new website, you can select this application pool
- Or, add a new website first. That will create an application pool automatically with the same name as the web site. Then, you edit the application pool and set it to **No Managed Code**

[image]

I hope that helps.

Comment: I created No managed code app pool before posting here and I understood part. What is the use of "Add application" as part of the Core Web API Deployment? Is there any specific link to follow steps. Thanks

Comment: Adding application is not specific to Core Web Api deployment. You can create another website as an application under the existing website. Regardless, if it's a Web Api or Website, adding an application makes it a sub application of the site. There are some benefits  of doing so. For example you can have multiple applications under the same site and don't necessarily need to create a separate domain for each application. A sub application can also share the configuration from the parent website and only application specific settings can be overridden.